# Google pubsub async java API clean shutdown

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am unable to get a Google pubsub Java async client to shutdown cleanly. After calling Subscriber.stopAsync() I am getting exceptions like this

```
    14:30:07.600 [grpc-default-worker-ELG-1-2] WARN  io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise - An exception was thrown by io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler$4.operationComplete()
          java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@724c721d rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@36bdb610[Shutting down, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 2, completed tasks = 19]
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
          at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:326) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
          at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:533) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
          at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:622) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
          at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.schedule(SerializingExecutor.java:93) ~[grpc-core-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.execute(SerializingExecutor.java:86) ~[grpc-core-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.onReady(ClientCallImpl.java:611) ~[grpc-core-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingClientStreamListener.onReady(ForwardingClientStreamListener.java:49) ~[grpc-core-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.internal.AbstractStream$TransportState.notifyIfReady(AbstractStream.java:298) ~[grpc-core-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.internal.AbstractStream$TransportState.onStreamAllocated(AbstractStream.java:237) ~[grpc-core-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientStream$TransportState.setHttp2Stream(NettyClientStream.java:249) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler$4.operationComplete(NettyClientHandler.java:521) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler$4.operationComplete(NettyClientHandler.java:509) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:504) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:483) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:103) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2CodecUtil$SimpleChannelPromiseAggregator.tryPromise(Http2CodecUtil.java:378) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2CodecUtil$SimpleChannelPromiseAggregator.trySuccess(Http2CodecUtil.java:344) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2CodecUtil$SimpleChannelPromiseAggregator.trySuccess(Http2CodecUtil.java:256) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.trySuccess(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:48) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.operationComplete(DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.java:52) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.operationComplete(DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.java:31) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:504) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:483) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:103) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.trySuccess(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:48) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.safeSuccess(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:696) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:258) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.removeBytes(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:338) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:409) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:934) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:360) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:901) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1396) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.forceFlush(SslHandler.java:1776) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapAndFlush(SslHandler.java:775) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.flush(SslHandler.java:752) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.flush(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:201) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler.gracefulClose(NettyClientHandler.java:631) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler.write(NettyClientHandler.java:300) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:738) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:730) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:816) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:723) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.write(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1061) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.write(AbstractChannel.java:295) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.WriteQueue$AbstractQueuedCommand.run(WriteQueue.java:174) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.WriteQueue.flush(WriteQueue.java:112) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.WriteQueue.access$000(WriteQueue.java:32) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.WriteQueue$1.run(WriteQueue.java:44) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:464) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_144]
```

I think this is indirectly caused by consumers trying to ack the message they processed.

My expectation is that after calling stopAsync() that no more messages would be pulled from the server but that messages buffered on the client would be delivered to my callback, and that I would be able to ack or nak those messages and any I am in the middle of processing, but I can't seem to make this work.

I can't see any other methods on Subscription I could call to effect a graceful shutdown, am I missing something?

Obviously these messages will eventually be re-delivered, but I would prefer to process the messages in my buffer before shutting down, and I would prefer to avoid "normal" exceptions in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

The way that `stopAsync()` works is that it runs the shutdown "sequence" but returns inmediately. Potentially leaving some work running Behind the scene. try calling `subscriber.stopAsync().awaitTerminated()` so the program waits until the service reaches a "Terminated" state.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this isn't the problem. The process has multiple subscriptions and after calling stopAsync() on each subscription it goes into a quiescent state where it's just waiting. After your post I did add the call to awaitTerminated() as each subscription is stopped, but this did not fix the problem.

Comment: Could you share the code that you are using to subscribe please?

Comment: https://github.com/symphonyoss/fugue/blob/master/google-fugue/src/main/java/org/symphonyoss/s2/fugue/google/pubsub/GoogleSubscriberManager.java#L182